# NoMethodError: undefined method `arel_table' for "User":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

*Rails 4.2*

**g.user_curator**

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `arel_table' for "User":String
```

My Tables:

```
create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",            limit: 255, default: "", null: false
    t.integer  "user_curator_id", limit: 4
    t.integer  "user_leader_id",  limit: 4
    t.datetime "created_at",                               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                               null: false
 end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  limit: 255, default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     limit: 255, default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "access_level",           limit: 4,   default: 0
    t.string   "first_name",             limit: 255
    t.string   "last_name",              limit: 255
    t.string   "middle_name",            limit: 255
  end
```

My Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_curator, :class_name => 'Group'
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_curator, :class => 'User', foreign_key: "user_curator_id"
end
```

Help the correct set associations for tables. In the group to be curator and leader (Table Users)

Comment: I can't see `user_curator_id` in your Users table schema

Comment: Your ques is not clear, explain what you want to set as associations

Comment: The group must be a link with the user table in the fields user_curator_id, user_leader_id, has_one

Comment: Here is a database schema
http://oi62.tinypic.com/20kym40.jpg

Answer (score 2):

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :curator, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_curator_id'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :group, foreign_key: 'user_curator_id'
end
```

This Will Work